# Global setting of spacing between items in itemize environment in TeXstudio

Tags: itemize, setspace

[image]

I have a problem with spacing between the bullet points. I have to keep my whole report in double spacing but I wish to reduce the space between bullet point of enumerate points. 
Please suggest me correct package or command.
Below is the current code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Power-train
    \item Comfort-train
    \item Safety
    \item Infotainment
    \item Telematics
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not undo the edit: I have redone it because this is the way to format posts correctly on this site.  As to your problem, you could try (untested) adding `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt} \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` to your preamble.

Comment: My apologies. @GuM

Comment: You can play with \itemsep (e.g \itemsep=-\baselineskip).

Comment: Oh, I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Please edit your post to provide compilable code. As it stands, this cannot possibly compile to produce the output you show.

Comment: @cfr - While fun, I am deleting my part of this digression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}% required for A4
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\setlist{itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Power-train
    \item Comfort-train
    \item Safety
    \item Infotainment
    \item Telematics
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```